# How can I define the reusable function in october cms?

Tags: octobercms

I just start OctoberCMS. I am struggling to define some functions which can be used throughout my entire application meaning it can be accessed from any plugin, pages, partial, layout. This is must to maintain clean code. I try to find any hints from the october cms official doc and no luck. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution which may help others:

**Create your own Plugin.**
There are countless way to create your own plugin in OctoberCMS but if you don't know how to do this than I think you should use Builder plugin which makes plugin creation ease (read its documentation for details).
https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder
Of course if you've already used the script above you probably know how to create plugin but this info can be useful for beginners who read this post in future.

**Create a custom class inside your plugin folder**
Open your plugin folder (for example in: ./plugins/oskar/tutorial ...where oskar is your author name and tutorial is the name of the plugin) and create a "classes" folder inside your plugin folder (./plugins/oskar/tutorial/classes). In the "classes" folder create a new PHP file called for example "MyClass.php" with this content:

```
<?php
namespace Oskar\Tutorial\Classes;
class MyClass
{
    public static function myMethod($param1)
    {
        return "Hello " . $param1;
    }
}
```

**Note:** keep in mind that you have to change namespace according to your real author and plugin name also the name of the file need to match the class name in it (oh and don't forget that namespace and class name is case sensitive)..

Extend Twig markup language with the new function
Open to edit your "Plugin.php" inside your plugin folder (./plugins/oskar/tutorial/Plugin.php) and add the following code:

```
public function registerMarkupTags()
{
    return [
        'functions' => [
            'myFunction' => ['\Oskar\Tutorial\Classes\MyClass', 'myMethod'],
        ]
    ];
}
```

Note: Again, don't forget to change namespace according to your needs.

You've done!

Now you can use this function in Twig like you did it before:

```
{{ myFunction('world!') }}
```

but you also can call the same method in the php section of your cms page:

```
use Oskar\Tutorial\Classes\MyClass;
function onStart()
{
    echo MyClass::myMethod('world!');    
}
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of functions you are wanting to make. You can call php functions from one plugin like this: Create and register a new plugin (Plugin A). You can then either create/call components to handle event handlers or create a 'classes' folder.

Here is an example of a plugin (Plugin B) to order products online. This calls your plugin with all your functions (Plugin A):

```php
use Author\PluginA\Classes\CustomFunctions;

function onSubmitOrder() {
    $customFunctions = new CustomFunctions;
    $inputs = Input::all();
    $order = $customFunctions->validateOrder($inputs);
    if ($order->success == true) {
        return $order;
    } else {
        return $order->error;
    }
}
```